# Expo start error. Failed to query all project files

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, npm-start

I have installed expo cli in my system. Also have created a project named calenderui but when i run the command 'expo-start' it only works partially . Don't know what to do. Below is the output that i am getting.

**H:\CALENDER\calenderui> expo start

Starting project at H:\CALENDER\calenderui

Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002

Failed to query all project files. Skipping `.expo.*` extension check...**